# CallKit : VOIP call is disconnecting when external call is declined

Tags: ios, swift, voip, opentok, callkit

I have implemented VOIP calling feature in my application using OpenTok SDK and CallKit framework. Calling feature is working most of the time. But there is one strange issue I have come across.

During a call, if any external cellular call appears and if I decline that external call then my running voip call also disconnects. This is happening some of the iPhone devices.

iPhone config:

- Model: iPhone 11
- iOS Version: 17.3

I have added loggers `CXEndCallAction` and `-provider:performEndCallAction` and debugged at my end. I found that `CXEndCallAction` is not executing from my end but still `-provider:performEndCallAction` is triggered by iOS along with my ongoing `callUUID`.

This is very strange behaviour I am observing in one of my iPhone device. I have tested this in 4 iPhone devices but i am facing this issue only in 1 iPhone.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That is quite strange that you are getting the ongoing callUUID there, I would recommend opening a feedback/bug report with Apple. This seems like a bug on their side

Comment: Thanks @abdulajet . I have reported same to Apple Developer forum. Let's see if I get any response there .